# lock user after many logging attempts in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I am using jwt tokens in nodejs to support authentication. Now I want to lock the user from the page when they give three wrong passwords. Does anybody know anything about this or resources that help with it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably want to timestamp and log each attempt.  If this is just a small application with no possibility of growing too large you could do this in memory.  If its a larger app then you would use a database.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. I will add the IP address of the user and save it in the database to blacklist it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try blacklisting the user after the 3rd attempt and the only way a user can log in again is when their token has been reset. Here is a good resource for blacklisting: https://auth0.com/blog/blacklist-json-web-token-api-keys/

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use cookies to block the user but then I realized that it's possible to clear the cookies on the browser. So I will use the IP address of the user and blacklist it.